# Show 1 div when click on h2 hide other divs

Tags: jquery

Hi in this code I need to show only the answer to the question I click on.
Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('document').ready(function ()
{
    $('.answer').hide();

    $('h2').on('click', function ()
    {
        $('.answer').show().siblings('.answer').hide();
    });

});
```

And here is the HTML I need to work with. I am not allowed to change the HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="main">
<h1>Een simpele bedrijfsstage FAQ (Veel gestelde vragen)</h1>
<h2>Heb ik als leerling tijdens mijn stage schoolvakanties?</h2>
      <div class="answer">
        <p>Je moet als leerling je houden aan de richtlijnen van het bedrijf. Dus als je vrij wilt hebben zul je bij begeleider een verlofaanvraag moeten indienen.</p>
      </div>
      <h2>Hoe kun je zien of dat een bedrijf een juiste erkenning heeft?</h2>
      <div class="answer">
        <p>Via de site: www.ecabo.nl  ->(helemaal bovenaan) ECABO leerbedrijven

Bedrijfsnaam:  ....... <br>
Postcode of plaats: (b.v. 's-Hertogenbosch) <br>
Opleiding:  (b.v. ICT-Beheerder)<br><br>

bevestig: Zoek <br><br>

Selecteer het bedrijf.<br><br>

Onder tabblad: Opleidingsmogelijkheden<br>
staan de opleidingen waarvoor het bedrijf erkend is. </p>
      </div>
      <h2>Wat moet ik doen als ik na het solliciteren niets meer van het bedrijf hoor?</h2>
      <div class="answer">
        <p>Neem direct  contact met het stageloket van de ICT-Academie op zodat die actie kunnen ondernemen.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So if I click on a `h2` the answer to that `h2` needs to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery's `.next` instead of `.siblings`.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('.answer').hide();

    $('h2').on('click', function ()
    {
        $('.answer').hide();
        $(this).next('.answer').show();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to switch states between all the `answer` divs. The `.not()` will remove the current desired `.answer`.

```
$('h2').on('click', function (){
    $(this).next('.answer').toggle();
    $('.answer').not($(this).next('.answer')).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('h2').on('click', function () { 
$(this).next('.answer').
show().
siblings('.answer').hide(); });
```

Refer the current h2 element instead of all '.answer' elements while showing the required answer.